# how python calculates predictions with linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm having trouble getting the formula that python use for linear predictions. I did a linear regression using:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_tr_pre_close,Y_tr_pre_close)
```

then I made predictions using:

```
predictions=lm.predict(X_te_pre_close)
```

I had great results with this model but now the problem is that I can't figure out how the `lm.predict()` formula works, the model should be ordinary least squares as I read in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)
in this case, the predictions formula supposes to be x'b (vector of coefficients * vector of explanatory variables) but it doesn't fit my results.

Comment: Can you post your attempt? The equation should be X * beta, where X is the matrix of predictors and beta is the column vector of coefficients and * is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

`LinearRegression` doesn't store the intercept as one of the coefficients, but as `intercept_`.
So you can reproduce the predict function like that:

```
# using sklearn
pred_sklearn = lm.predict(X_te_pre_close)
# using coefficients directly:
pred_coef = X_te_pre_close @ lm.coef_.T + lm.intercept_
assert all(pred_coef == pred_sklearn)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! actually, I did the right calculation but making it manually I missed some decimals and so the result was different!

Comment: Glad to hear this! Since weirdly I seem to care about random internet points, would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you?